# How to apply a seasonal index into an eCDF?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn, wasserstein

I am doing a Before/After analysis, which is aiming at evaluating the effect of a **change**. Assume I have made a change at the beginning of *June-2022*, and I want to evaluate the effect of the change based on a one-month interval. This results in two time series, related to two distinct months, i.e., the first one is for *May-2022* (before the change was performed), and the second one is for *June-2022* (After the change was performed).

I am evaluating the effect of the change based on the eCDFs of the two periods, using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

The issue in my evaluation is that even without any change, June would have been different from May, i.e., there is seasonality in my data. Suppose I can capture that seasonality by using historical data from 2021. My question is how to apply this seasonality in the eCDFs.

What I have in mind is to (1) use the eCDFs of *May-2021* and *June-2021*, and find the difference between them using the Wasserstein distance (which as far as I understand, since my data is one-dimensional, the distance is the signed area between the two eCDFs), and then, (2) finding a seasonal index based on the Wasserstein distance, and applying that index to *May-2022* (I am not sure how to do this part).

So, my goal is compare eCDF of *June-2022* with a **shifted** eCDF of *May-2022* to have a fairer comparison.

Any help is appreciated. Particularly, how to calculate an index based on the Wasserstein distance, and how to use that index to shift the eCDF of *May-2022* (a multiplicative index? can I multiply all *May-2022* data points by that index?).